# WCF Service authentication messages

Tags: wcf, authentication, exception

I'm writing a WCF service with authentication and have stumbled across this: I can't seem to define the messages returned in the event of an error in authentication (that is to say: user is not authenticated).

I have an IErrorHandler implementation in place, however that doesn't appear to catch the exceptions thrown (`SecurityTokenException` or `FaultException<T>`) during auth. I can confirm that it works in the rest of scenarios, however.

**Is there something I'm missing here? Or is it really not possible to catch and handle exceptions thrown in auth?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IErrorHandler can't handle the exception that happens in the authentication process. Why do you want to handle the authencation exception?

Your client side can catch the authentcation exception.

Comment: I was hoping to supply some nicer messages

Comment: If you use UserName client credential, and provide your UsernameAndPasswordValidator, you may throw your exception in this class.

Comment: I am, as it stands. Exceptions in there don't appear to be getting caught by the IErrorHandler

Comment: If you do need to catch such SecurityTokenException, you may try to develop a customized SecurityTokenAuthenticator and catch such exception in that class and then you may wrap the exception with what you want. And IErrorHandler will be functional when the authentication is done and the service starts to process the request.

Comment: I'll look in to writing a `SecurityTokenAuthenticator`. Thanks.